# Styling TreeView's row using CSS

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

What is the class-name in which I should use to style a TreeView's rows?

I've tried GtkCellRendererText, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, just use GtkTreeView:Hover or GtkTreeView:Selected